Get SpinnerText from Espresso
After I select an item from spinner using index how do I get the name of the item selected and then compare it with the results shown on page.
I tried a custom matcher to get spinner text but it throws a performException error.

Have you looked at the documentation?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
